# MapView doesn't show all pins at first

Tags: swift

Map View does not show all pins at first. So, I must to zoom in/out to see all of them.
What I should do If I would like to see all pins overlaying each other?

As I remember the issue not exists in previous versions of Swift, like 7 or 8.

```
let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:     51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")

let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")
```

Thank you!

Comment: current swift version is 5 ------  7,8 is yet to come

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after you add the annotations

```
self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```